# For add-ins that support "Word 2016", exactly which versions are supported?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-store

I've got a Word add-in on AppSource.  Under "products supported", the AppSource page lists:

- Word 2016+
- Word 2016 for Mac
- Word Online

However, for some versions of Word 2016, people are not able to install it.  Here are some examples:

- It has always worked for Office 365 (this is indicated as Word version 16.31 though it is apparently not Word 2016).
- It works now for personal Word 2016 (non-subscription) but it didn't about a month ago (a Word upgrade seems to have fixed this).
- It doesn't work for the latest business Word 2016 (also non-subscription).  People get an error saying that the add-in is not supported on their version of Word.

Here is an example error message:

[image]

which isn't helpful since the store says it works in Word 2016!

How can I know which versions of Word are actually supported by my add-in?

Is it possible that the add-in can be installed on business non-subscription Word, but that it isn't being installed correctly?

=== UPDATE ===

In case it matters, these are the requirements in my manifest:

```
<Requirements>
   <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="File" MinVersion="1.1"/>
      <Set Name="AddinCommands" MinVersion="1.1"/>
   </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

Comment: Is it possible that these businesses haven't allowed their installed version to update? Businesses often explicitly don't allow auto updates, where most with a personal version probably would (as it's the installation default).

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister, I was talking to an IT person at the company and they told me the version of Word and it was a recent one so that doesn't seem to be the issue.  From what you are saying, it sounds like a recent non-subscription business Word 2016 should work with my add-in so that is promising at least.

Comment: FWIW it doesn't matter *when* someone purchases a 2016 installable - the code base will be the same as a version bought two or three years ago. If there are updates that improve something related to an Office JS add-in, fine. But only the subscription versions are going to update features and functionality in any substantial way - that's one of the main "selling" points for Office 365 (there never has been subscription version of 2016!). The same will pertain to Office 2019 - the API requirement sets are going to be more or less static. See the answer from Wenbo Shi...

Comment: @CindyMeister, thanks for the clarification, but then it seems more mysterious why my add in doesn't work for Word 2016 when AppSource says it does.  If I understand you correctly, the version of Word 2016 shouldn't matter and my add in should work for all versions of Word 2016 but that doesn't seem to be the case in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll present my best understanding based on the comments and answers here.  I'll try to update this as I get better info.

- Office 365 Word (aka subscription word) -- Supports all add ins because Office 365 Word is updated frequently.  It would be great if the AppSource page listed Office 365 Word as a supported platform to avoid confusion.
- Personal Word 2016 (aka non-subscription Word) -- Supports my add-in with the two requirements in the original question. The [Microsoft docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/add-in-commands-requirement-sets) are incorrect since that page says that the AddInCommands 1.1 requirement is supported in Outlook only.
- Business Word 2016 (aka non-subscription Word)

  - No `<Requirements>` tag in manifest -- Your add-in can be installed, but functionality is greatly reduced and is a bad UX. It seems that you can't add ribbon buttons.  Users need to "Insert" the add-in each time you want to use it which is kind of like installing it.
  - `<Set Name="AddinCommands" MinVersion="1.1"/>` in manifest -- You can't use the add-in at all.

The Microsoft folks pointed me to this [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets) a few times, but I honestly don't understand what info that page provides about Word 2016.  This appears to be the only relevant paragraph:

> The build number for Office 2016 installed via MSI is 16.0.4266.1001. This version only contains the WordApi 1.1 requirement set.

My add-in does not work on installations of business Word 2016 with a more recent build number.

Answer (score 1):

If you correctly mark the requirement set version in your Addin manifest file, then when users try to insert Addin from AppSource, it only list the addins whose required API requirement set version is supported by your current Office client.

For Word APIs, please check below page for the details:

[Word JavaScript API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets)

Comment: Thank you for responding, but this doesn't help answer my question.

Comment: Wenbo, can you clarify why users can't install my add-in on Word 2016 even though AppSource says my add-in supports Word 2016?

Comment: In this case, the requirement set <Set Name="AddinCommands" MinVersion="1.1"/> has a minimal version requirements of which Office 2016 build it starts to be supported. Please check [Add-in commands requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/add-in-commands-requirement-sets) for detail.